# How to negate bytes in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to work this [crypto puzzle](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/e6284e/encrypted_message/) someone posted, and I was trying to automate it in python3, and hitting some trouble.  It's driving me crazy I can't figure out how to do this.

It involves doing a base64 decode, which gives a bytes type.

I want to iterate over this collection of bytes, and do a bitwise negation of each byte.  Which is to say, 10010001 (145) should become 01101110 (110), for example.  The ~ operator is giving me two's compliment, though, and producing negative ints.  I want to work with unsigned bytes.

How can I do this in python 3?

psudocode for what I want to do:

```
[ bitwise_negate(x) for x in my_byte_array ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the python `base64` module to first decode the string into its corresponding bytes then you can xor each byte against 255 (11111111) to get the resulting ascii pointcode and use `chr` to get the actualy character

```py
import base64
string = 'l4uLj8XQ0J2Wi9GThtDMzJGUmbKluw=='
decoded = base64.decodebytes(bytes(string, encoding='utf-8'))
print("".join([chr(item ^ 255) for item in decoded]))
```

Comment: So the answer is to xor 255.